# clicking ng-repeat link repeatedly calls script files

Tags: angularjs, node.js, mongodb

I am using MEAN for my Application, i have an ng-repeat attribute to fetch data from my db in my "questions.jade" file. once i click on individual link of the repeat values, it gives me such an error `"Synchronous XMLHttpRequest on the main thread is deprecated because of its detrimental effects to the end user's experience. For more help, check http://xhr.spec.whatwg.org/."` and repeatedly calls all the scripts files, have attached the console and terminal screenshots

questions.jade file

```
.container(ng-controller="bQuestionListCtrl")
    table.table.table-hover.table-striped.table-condensed
        thead
            tr
               th Question
               th Category
        tbody
            tr(ng-repeat="question in questions")
                td
                    a(href="/questions/{{question._id}}") {{ question.question }}
                td {{ question.category }}
```

question-detail.jade

```
.container(ng-controller="bQuestionDetailCtrl")

   h1 {{question.question}}
```

app.js

```
 angular.module('app', ['ngResource', 'ngRoute']);

    angular.module('app').config(function($routeProvider, $locationProvider)
    {

        $locationProvider.html5Mode({
            enabled: true,
            requireBase: false
        });
        $routeProvider
            .when('/questions', { templateUrl: 'partials/questions/question',
                controller:'bQuestionListCtrl', resolve:routeRoleChecks.user})
            .when('/questions/:id', { templateUrl: 'partials/questions/question-detail',
                controller:'bQuestionDetailCtrl', resolve:routeRoleChecks.user})

    });

    angular.module('app').run(function($rootScope, $location){
        $rootScope.$on('$routeChangeError', function(evt, current, previous, rejection){
            if(rejection === 'not authorized'){
                $location.path('/');
            }
        })
    })
```

console of browser(about 15 script files are called 7000 times)
[image]
terminal view
[image]

How can i rectify this?

Comment: Could you please show us `resolve:routeRoleChecks.user` code.

Comment: `var routeRoleChecks = {
        admin: { auth: function(bAuth){
            return bAuth.authorizeCurrentUserForRoute('admin')
        }},
        user: { auth: function(bAuth){
            return bAuth.authorizeAuthenticatedUserForRoute()
        }}
    }`

Comment: I expected to see HTTP call. Are you using jQuery for HTTP request, don't you?